# How to specifying what msbuild version to use for a given project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

My build machine should compile some projects that been created in vs 2010 with MSBuild 4.0.
And some projects that also been created in vs2010 to build them using MSBuild v13.0.

Any ideas how I can specify in the project file or by some other way what msbuild to use for this given project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .csproj has a start tag called Project which has an optional attribute called ToolsVersion. The version of the toolset MSBuild uses to determine the values for $(MSBuildBinPath) and $(MSBuildToolsPath).

Via msbuild command-line you could set those properties to determine which version of the msbuild you are going to use.

source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bcxfsh87.aspx)